# How to access all files in all sub directories using shell script?

Tags: shell

I want to execute following command on all files of a directory and also on all files in sub directories of that directory:

```
cat filename | col -b > filename
```

this command will remove control `M` or `^M` character from the file and works fine with single file. Please help ... 
I tried below command but doesn't work. It works with single directory but not with sub directories.

```
for i in *
do
        cat i | col -b > i
done
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. You forgot the dollar sign on the variable interpolation, it should properly be double-quoted; and you cannot use redirection like that because you are overwriting the file before it can be opened for reading. *(And* the [cat is useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.gif or .jpeg' -o -exec sed -i 's/^M//' {} \;
```

this is what your looking for   ^M it works in all file to remove the images. just check it in you are code

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/^M//' {} \;`

Note, do the ^M by hitting ctrl-V then ctrl-m, not just ^M
If you want to only hit a subset of files, then specify an appropriate regexp and pass that to find as (most likely) `-iname` - see `man find` for the options

Comment: It works and remove ^M in all files, But it may also remove this from all images. Resulting it corrupt all my images. So plz suggest something that it will not remove ^M from images...

Comment: Then you should have asked for that in the first place - `col` will also corrupt images.

Comment: that's ok, its my mistake because i am not aware of shell scripting. But what should i do now..

Comment: If your images all have a uniform file name, add something like `-name '*.png' -o` before the `-exec`.